# Class 'ViewController' has no initializers | Swift

Tags: swift

I'm building a calculator and I keep getting the message "Class 'ViewController' has no initializers"

Not sure why I keep getting this message. Any ideas?

```
'import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var numberOnScreen: Double = 0;
    var previousNumber: Double = 0;
    var performingMath: false
    var operation = 0;'
```

Comment: Typo: `var performingMath = false`.  Also, Swift doesn't need the semicolons.

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo:

```
var performingMath = false
```

Answer (score 0):

all properties needs be initialized in Swift if you does not using the unwrapper symbol '?' or '!' and you property needs be a type, for example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var numberOnScreen: 0
}
```

it yet is wrong way to set the type, the number zero is a int, but when you use ':' the compiler is waiting the type, not the value, to fix that, you need to set first it type:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var numberOnScreen: Int = 0
}
```

that way above inicialized the ViewController with numbeROnScreen aways with zero, but if yout need to pass the value on a constructor you must to do:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var numberOnScreen: Int

    init(newValue: Int) {
        self.numberOnScreen = newValue
        super.init(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Or if you want pass the value of numberOnScreen after initialize the ViewController, you must add the icon '?' to tell to ViewController that property going to be inicialize after initialized:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var numberOnScreen: Int?
}
```

But you need to be care to use that property above, it can be null, and to user it you need to use the unwrapper '!', but the right way to access that value is using if let or guard

```
class Calculator {

    init() {
        let controller = ViewController()
        controller.numberOnScreen = 1
        guard let numberOfScreen = controller.numberOnScreen else {
            return
        }
        print(numberOfScreen)
    }

}
```

So, if you want to se more:

Optional Values

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional

Statements ( about if let, guard and more )

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html